# How to show Page Location in GA4 reports?

Tags: google-analytics

We moved to the Google Analytics v4 and data is coming thru all fine, however I want to edit the reports to show the page location instead of the page title:

[image: realtime report]

In the `Views by Page title and screen name`, I want to edit it to show the views by page location. Many of our pages use the same page title, so we can't get a better view of where the user is.

The same thing happens when I try to create a Path Analysis report:

[image: Path analysis]

Is it possible to customize the GA4 to show the page locations in the reports?

Comment: I closed this question because questions about Google Analytics are better suited for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to customize the GA4 to show the page locations in the reports?

Yes it is possible.

Its a bit easier now.  This can be achieved OOTB on the Events page that is displayed inside of the Reports parent location.

- Go to Engagement -> Events
- Click "Customize Report"
- Save as new report with a proper name (i.e. Demo - Event for Page Locations)
- On the right side bar, under Report Data, click on Dimensions
- **Remove** Event name **or** no longer make it the default.
- Click Add Dimension and select "Page Location" and set it as default.
- Click Apply and save your current report

> Tip - If your single GA4 property is applied to multiple sub domains, and you want this report to focus on a specific domain, don't forget apply a filter -> hostname -> `<the sub domain checked>` , all before you press apply.

You should now see Full URL page locations under this custom report. **Also you can double click any full URL you see listed, to then right click and open in a new tab.**